# Remove Navigation Bar shadow Colour on iPhone 6/6plus

Tags: ios, iphone

[image]

I'm trying to remove this white stroke. I've previously fixed this using

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

and it work perfectly on iPhone 4s,5,5s and iOS 7/8. But for some reason on iPhone 6/6+ that whte shadow is still there.
I've also tried this to no result. It just makes the shadow a darker colour than my current navBar bgColour (white: 0 alpha 0.9).

```
UIView * bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.height, self.navigationController.navigationBar.width, 1)]; 
bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.9];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:bgView];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:nil];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following, this at least works for me.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I also then set a custom colour

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor XXXXXX]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set navigation's bar property clipsToBounds to YES